# How do I pass field name as a parameter into a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using one stored procedure in which I send `@columnname` whose type in database is `float` and I also declare parameter `float`.
When I pass column name as float then it gives the error:

> Msg 8114, error converting data type nvarchar to float.

This is my test query

```
Declare @column float
set @column = 'S_E1'
select Avg(@column) from TBL_SENSORS
```

And when I change parameter type to `varchar` then it gives me this error:

> Msg 8117, Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator.

```
Declare @column varchar
set @column = 'S_E1'
select Avg(@column) from TBL_SENSORS
```

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE :**

This is my stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAvgColumn]
    @ColumnName float,
    @StartDate DateTime,
    @EndDate DateTime,
    @Start int,
    @End int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @Skip int = 0
    declare @Take int = 4
    declare @count int = 0

    set @count = (select count(@ColumnName) from TBL_SENSORS Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between   @StartDate and @EndDate And ( @ColumnName Between @Start And @End ))

    while(@Skip < @count)
    Begin
        select avg(@ColumnName)
        from 
            (select 
                 @ColumnName as cc,
                 row_number() over (order by RECORD_TIMESTAMP) as rn
             from 
                 TBL_SENSORS 
             Where 
                 RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between @StartDate and @EndDate 
                 And (@ColumnName Between @Start And @End)
            ) T
    where 
        rn > @Skip and 
        rn <= @Skip + @Take

    set @Skip = @Skip + @Take
end
END
```

Comment: How does one take the average of a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column-name and/or table-name as parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791764/column-name-and-or-table-name-as-parameters)

Comment: Are you trying to return an average of a field whose name you are passing as a parameter?

Comment: @Sunny Why is `ColumnName` a float?

Comment: DataType of Columnname is float that's why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
Declare @column varchar 
set @column = 'S_E1' 

SET @SQL = 'select Avg(' + quotename(@column) + ') from TBL_SENSORS'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Update: applied both suggestions for `quotename` and `sp_executesql`

New procedure: you can use dynamic SQL to place data into a temp table with a known schema. Refer to column based on alias: ColumnToAvg. Instead of TBL_SENSORS use #TempSensors.

Note: in production you'll want to check if #TempSensors exists and drop if it does.

```
SET @SQL = 'Select RECORD_TIMESTAMP, '
    + quotename(@ColumnName)   
    + ' as ColumnToAvg 
       INTO #TempSensors
       from TBL_SENSORS
       Where RECORD_TIMESTAMP Between @StartDate and @EndDate 
       And @ColumnName Between @Start And @End'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
    , N'@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime, @Start int, @End int'
    , @StartDate , @EndDate, @Start, @End
```

Comment: You should use [quotename](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#quotestring) when you build the query. `'select Avg(' + quotename(@colom) + ') from TBL_SENSORS'` to protect yourself against SQL injection.

Comment: @Jeff O please check question now i added the stored procedure in question

Comment: I agree with Mikael about the SQL injection issue. I also agree with @Curt on his suggestion about sp_executesql - that can take parameters for better protection against sql injection.