# How to get Column value without knowing column name ? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sysobjects

I have table name as `@Table_Name`

I have column value as `@Value` but don't have the column name (but that exist at 1st position and can be Seek_id or prov_id ...I have to compare my value with this id )

How can I compare that table column name value ?

I want something like

```
SELECT * FROM @Table_Name
WHERE Table.Column[1].Value = @Value
```

for example `@Table_Name = bb_match` and `@Value = 6`

Comment: You cannot do this - SQL Server needs a column name - it cannot use ordinal position to refer to a column in a table

Comment: You may be able to use some dynamic SQL querying sys.columns to find the first column

Comment: you can use the ordinal_position field in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table to find the first column of the given table.

Comment: this is near to my solution but not showing value only showing column name of that row ..(sent by my friend):

Comment: DECLARE @column_name varchar(20)
set *column_name = (SELECT top 1 column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'bb_match')
select * from bb_match
where *column_name = '8'  (*=@)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column-name and/or table-name as parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791764/column-name-and-or-table-name-as-parameters) and numerous other [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+column+table+name+variable)

Answer (score 2):

Possible this be helpful for you -

**Query:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.bb_match') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.bb_match

CREATE TABLE dbo.bb_match (seek_id INT, prov_id INT)

INSERT INTO dbo.bb_match (seek_id, prov_id)
VALUES (6, 1), (2, 6) 

DECLARE 
      @ColumnID TINYINT
    , @Value INT 
    , @TableName SYSNAME
    , @SQL NVARCHAR(500)

SELECT 
      @ColumnID = 1
    , @Value = 6
    , @TableName = 'dbo.bb_match'

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE [' + c.name + '] = ' + CAST(@Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
WHERE o.[type] = 'U' -- <-- only for tables columns
    AND s.name + '.' + o.name = @TableName
    AND c.column_id = @ColumnID

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Shorter, but unsafe** (sys.columns contains column_name for tables, views, procedures, ...):

```
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE [' + c.name + '] = ' + CAST(@Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
    AND c.column_id = @ColumnID
```

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

**Output:**

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.bb_match WHERE [seek_id] = 6
```

**Results:**

```
seek_id     prov_id
----------- -----------
6           1
```

Comment: Where did you specify the column position. he want to compare the value with tthe first column.

Comment: I have table name *table_Name and column value *value not column name ...How can I search in  *table_Name I know that column position is 1st( 1st column in table ) .....

Comment: I have value which I have to compare with 1st column in the table that is id ( name is anything like seek_id or prov_id)

Comment: Devart thanks for your ans ...SELECT * FROM dbo.bb_match WHERE [seek_id] = 6 ( but my column id is not seek_id ....that can be any think like seek_id or prov_id )  means I will search in any table ...1st column value I have only table name ....and value for campare with 1st column but dont know 1st column name ..please help me ..its very urgent

Comment: Yippee! & you're welcome @user2369561 :))). In case this solution fully suits you, I would be glad if you could confirm it.

Comment: I was trying to write one SP that will take any table name and any id  then search that table and compare 1st column with my id then show then result / row ....

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @sql varchar(MAX)
declare @tablename varchar(100) = 'MyTable' --add your table name here
declare @value varchar(100) = 'SomeValue' -- add your desired value hree

select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tablename + ' WHERE '
+ name 
+ ' = ''' + @value + ''''
from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@tablename) and column_id = 1

exec (@sql)
```

There are three parts to this. First I'm declaring three strings. `@sql` is where I will build up the query, `@tablename` and `@value` are the table and search value to look in/for. I've put in the dummy values MyTable and SomeValue to show what I'm talking about

Next I build up the sql statement. The first line sets the string as `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE`

I then add in the column name by selecting Name from the SQL SERver system table `sys.columns`, filtering on the first column (`column_id = 1`) and the table name

The next step is to add the value we want to search for in the column.

Finally, `EXEC(@sql)` interprets the string as a command and runs it.

Comment: thanks jaloopa .... but getting error Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".

Comment: select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + bb_match + ' WHERE '
+ name 
+ ' = ' + 8
from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('TCONTROL') and column_id = 1

exec (@sql)

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@sql" means you didn't include the first line. Fill in the required table name and value and run the entire script

Comment: I've modified the query and added some explanation. If you want to see what the final query looks like, replace EXEC(@sql) with SELECT @sql