# pass table name as parameter in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to pass table name as parameter and I want to that parameter in where clause

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[bb_GetPrepositionInfo] 
    @userid INT,@propId INT,@tabName varchar(50)
AS 
      SET NOCOUNT ON 
      SET XACT_ABORT ON  

     BEGIN TRAN 

    SELECT *
    FROM   @tblname
    WHERE  ([acq_id] = @propId AND [user_id] = @userid) 

   COMMIT
    GO
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic SQL (passing table name as parameter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325044/dynamic-sql-passing-table-name-as-parameter)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column-name and/or table-name as parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5791764/11683)

Answer (score 3):

Not tested but You need to use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[bb_GetPrepositionInfo] 
    @userid INT,@propId INT,@tabName varchar(50)
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @SQL varchar(250)
    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QuoteName(@tabName) + ' where acq_id=' + Quotename(@propId) + ' AND user_id=' + Quotename(@userid)
    EXEC (@SQL)

    COMMIT
GO
```

Comment: Mr_eclair ...error   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure bb_GetPrepositionInfo, Line 10
Invalid column name 'propId'.

Comment: exec bb_GetPrepositionInfoByTable 523,35, 'bb_acquire_prvider' ....getting this error .....Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '35'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '523'.

Comment: I have change proc name bb_GetPrepositionInfo to bb_GetPrepositionInfoByTable

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[bb_GetPrepositionInfo] 
  DECLARE  @userid INT
  DECLARE   @propId INT 
  DECLARE  @tabName varchar(50)
  DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(200)
AS 
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
  SET XACT_ABORT ON  

  BEGIN TRAN

  SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * from ' + @tabName +'WHERE  [acq_id]='+  @propId +'AND   [user_id] = '+ @userid 
  EXEC (@sqlCommand)

  COMMIT
 GO
```

Comment: You don't need "@sqlCommand varchar(200)" as a parameter if you are going to reset it every time in the procedure.  Consider instead declaring it as a variable within the body of the procedure.