# MS SQL Linked Servers And Using In FROM Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a very basic test stored procedure, shown below. This proc is reading data in a different database, in a different server. To do this I am using a linked server. From what I have read, I need to change the FROM clause to this:

```
[linked server name].[database name].[schema name].[table name]
```

However, I would like to pass in the linked server name and database name as parameters and use them in my FROM clause. I am not concerned with injection attacks, etc. I will be passing this in from a config file.

```
create PROC [dbo].[SelectTEST] 
@GU UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@LINKED_SERVER_NAME nvarchar(max),
@DATABASE_NAME nvarchar(max)
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN

    SELECT [GU]
    FROM '[' + @LINKED_SERVER_NAME +'].['+ @DATABASE_NAME + '].[Test Table] '
    WHERE  ([GU] = @GU OR @GU IS NULL) 

    COMMIT
```

This is a big mess of syntax errors. Is it possible to pass in these parameters and use in my stored procedure? I would have to make this change to a bunch of different procs, so sorta trying to find the a succinct solution...

Comment: You need to script the whole statement in dynamic sql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass table name as parameter in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280781/pass-table-name-as-parameter-in-sql-server)

Comment: There is no other way besides dynamic sql?

Comment: Nope, there's no other support for dynamic object names like that.