# SQL how to update table not referencing it by its name?

Tags: sql

I need to create procedure that accepts `@TableName` and `@ColumnName` as parameters and updates the table depending on a supplied table/column name

```
create My_Procedure (@TableName varchar(50), @ColumnName varchar(50))
as
update @TableName
set @ColumnName = '2013-01-01'
go
```

But the update statement in the procedure won't work.
Please help me to find a way to rewrite the statement so it will work without using dynamic SQL. Maybe using `object_id` of the table and column somehow?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: This is generally not possible.  You can do something similar with dynamic SQL, but it's inadvisable.  Generally speaking, if you are trying to do this, you either have a badly defined database, or a poor DML strategy.

Comment: Looks like SQL Server. If so, there's no way to do it without dynamic SQL. also, its just bad practice to allow unfettered updates to any table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use SQL Server, you must use dynamic SQL to do this sort of things:

```
create My_Procedure (@TableName varchar(50), @ColumnName varchar(50))
as
begin
  declare @sql nvarchar(max)
  set @sql = 'update '+@TableName +' set '+@ColumnName+' = ''2013-01-01'''
  exec @sql
end
```

However, note that this can basically can do anything to the database, so while there are legitimate uses for dynamic sql, this kind of general approach might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you will need to look into dynamic sql, check this SO related question.
[Column-name and/or table-name as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791764/column-name-and-or-table-name-as-parameters)