# Get column name as parameter in ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to solve this but for the moment i don't have a solution in my mind.
I have this variable as a multiple select in SSRS and the variable itself has two values, which are column names.

In the query, for example, the parameter name is:

```
@column (It has two values, name and surname)
```

If the first value is selected the query should be:

```
AND name IS NULL
```

But if the two are selected, it should be:
WHERE name and surname are null.

How do i resolve this?
I got some reference from here but still i can't figure it out:
[Column-name and/or table-name as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791764/column-name-and-or-table-name-as-parameters)

Comment: Your question isn't 100% clear to me, but it *seems* you will have to resort to dynamic sql.

Comment: Am I right in thinking your parameter @Column can equal one of the following: name, surname or name and surname?

Comment: @ChristianBarron, yes, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correct and you want to change your where based on what is selected in your @Column parameter then you need sql like the below to reflect this:

```
Select *
From table
Where (@Column = 'name' and name is null) or
      (@Column = 'surname' and surname is null) or
      (@Column = 'name and surname' and surname is null and name is null)
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this is what i need :)